# ¿Cómo puedo diseñar una extensión de tipo cadena que represente un día de la semana y devuelva el número correspondiente? en SWIFT

Tags: swift

Necesito diseñar una extension de tipo String que represente un dia de la semana y me regrese el numero correspondiente iniciando con domingo = 1 y finaliza con Sabado = 7

Aquí hay una idea que tengo, pero no sé cómo poner el Int para el valor del día de la semana:

```
extension String{
   var domingo: String {return self}
   var lunes: String {return self}
   var martes:String {return self}
   var miercoles: String {return self}
   var jueves: String {return self}
   var vierne: String {return self}
   var sabado: String {return self}
}
```

Otra idea es esta, pero no sé cómo devolver el número o si su valor para agregar los días de la semana a continuación a diasSemana:

```
extension String{
   var diasSemana:String{
       return self
   }
   func numero() -> Int{
   return self
   }
}
.dias
.numero
```

Por favor, ¿alguien puede ayudarme? Soy nuevo con Swift y es confuso.

Comment: ¿Podrias mostrar un ejemplo de cómo usarías la extensión?, o ¿Qué es lo que pretendes lograr?. Fácilmente podrías usar un _enum_ para representar los días de la semana.

Comment: Si claro , deje el ejemplo con una imagen espero no sea problema , necesito diseñar una extension de tipo String que represente un dia de la semana y me regrese el numero correspondiente iniciando con domingo = 1 y finaliza con Sabado = 7. Pretendo lograr eso

Comment: Sigo sin tener muy claro como lo usarias..., por ejemplo esto seria valido? `"hola mundo".sabado` ??

Comment: los dias de la semana tienen un valor domingo = 1 , lunes= 2 , martes = 3 , miercoles = 4 , jueves = 5 , viernes = 6 , sabado = 7 entonces necesito usar la extencion con el tipo de valor String donde por medio de una funcion o variable conmutada pueda devolverme el valor entero del correspondiente dia

Comment: Bueno, según lo que has mencionado, este no es un caso de uso para una _extension_. Estaría más apropiado usar un _enum_.

Comment: Ese es el problema que me estan solicitando hacer uso de extension y el no tener una mac fisica , uso una pero remota me ha hecho tener limitantes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ayudarte de los `Enum` para que tengas los días:

```
enum Dias: Int {
    case domingo = 1
    case lunes
    case martes
    case miercoles
    case jueves
    case viernes
    case sabado
}
```

Creas la extensión con la función que reciba como parámetro de tipo `Dias` y devuelves el `rawValue` de tipo `Int` de ese `enum`:

```
extension String {
    func getDiaAInt(stringDia: Dias) -> Int {
        return stringDia.rawValue
    }
}
```

El resultado sería:

```
print("".getDiaAInt(stringDia: .domingo))//Imprime 1
print("".getDiaAInt(stringDia: .jueves))//Imprime 5
```